# Checkout/cart order totals and shipping showing zero values after upgrade to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

After upgrading from Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.4.3, checkout order subtotal, grand total, shipping and everything in summary or cart page (not popup) are showing zero values.

I've tried to disable our One step page extension and switched to Luma theme, but its still showing the same.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @SMDev, Do you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot post a comment, but was about to suggest you check for other modules that might hook the function, have you solved the issue? Could you repost the output of module:status ?

Comment: Hi, no problem. I've found a solution/patch related to a core bug but didn't try it yet:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34799#issuecomment-993803522